# What I found so far the blinking text isnt working

Tags: html, css

I would like to have blinking email link and also the line that says Hello Professor. What i have found so far hasnt worked. Any help would be great. This is what I have tried so far text-decoration:blink; with no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Randy's first html web page !</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{background-image:url('Koala.gif');} 
h1
{
text-align:center;
font-size:500%;
}
h2
{
text-align:center;
font-size:250%;
}
p
{
text-align:center;
font-size:200%;
color:#00fff0;
}
div
{
background-color:#efffff;
}
a
{
text-align:center;
}
th
{
background-color:green;
}
tr
{
background-color:green;
}
table 
{
width: 200px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
}
#google-link 
{ 
margin: 0 auto; 
display: block;
font-size:250%;
color:#00ff00;
} 
#Mail-link
{
margin: 0 auto; 
display: block;
font-size:250%;
color:#00ff00;
text-decoration:blink;
}
</style>
</head>
<h1> Hello Professor</h1>
<h2> By: Randy White</h2>
<P> It's getting better as the term goes on.</P> 
<P>Week 2</P>
<P><img src="Hydrangeas.jpg" width="150" height="100" alt="Hydrangeas.jpg"></P> 
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Year</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>December</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>2010</td>
</tr>
</table>
<a id="google-link" href="http://www.google.com">Visit Google!</a>
<a id="Mail-link" href="mailto:randywhite30@neb.rr.com"> Contact Me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if I did want to I wouldnt be asking.

Comment: Your code works for me on Firefox 4. What browser are you using?

Comment: Well, that gives you another reason not to use blink then -- not all browsers support it.

Comment: yep I found a page that says IE doesnt support the blink

Comment: I think this is the canonical example of "It's not a bug, it's a feature."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for <blink>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

Answer (score 4):

IE (and probably other browsers) don't support `text-decoration: blink`.  Just don't do this anyhow - blink is the epitome of bad taste and design on the web.  You may as well have an animated background and MIDI music.  I think Google may even hurt your ranking, and it will hurt my feelings.  ;)

**Let me reassure you** - there are much better ways to draw attention to page elements.

Comment: +1 Midi music - i detest! But marginally lesser than blinking text :-)

Comment: You can mute your sound, but what are you going to do, turn off your monitor?  Not really an option while operating the computer.  All you can do is click back and never, ever visit the site again.  Ever.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for the `<annoy-the-crap-out-of-the-user>` tag :-)

But, seriously, if a browser doesn't support it, you have a couple of options.

The first is the relatively easy, don't support that browser. And, though easy, it may not be feasible.

The second is just as easy, don't use blinking text - that would be my preference but I'm going to assume you have a real need for it. However, you should take everyone's advice and at least *look into* a different way of doing this.

The third is with Javascript (I'd go jQuery myself) where you can set up timers to blink the text yourself. Not pretty but sometimes kludges are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that most HTML clients will not display blinking text, as it's highly visually intrusive.

Even if they did support it, I would ***strongly encourage*** you not to avail yourself of the capability for the above reason.