# Each Blink as to Display different messages

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website, and I need to display different messages each time. I used `<blink>` tags in HTML.

With `<blink>` we can only make one text blink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for <blink>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

Comment: jQuery has blink feature

Answer (score 1):

```js
var messages = ["OK, I admit...", "...that I only answered this...", "...because I was curious to see...", "...if it could be done in one line...", "...which apparently it can...", "...though it is silly to do so..."];

setInterval(((i =-1, m = document.getElementById("message")) => () => m.innerHTML = m.innerHTML==="" ? messages[i=(i+1)%messages.length] : "")(), 1000);
```

```html
<p id="message"></p>
```