# How do I blink text in latest record in bootgrid table?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mysql

I have used bootgrid table which is below. I was wondering if possible, how can I add text e.g. **"New"** in latest record i.e. row.

Blinking text code I found is here: [Blinking text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105152/alternative-for-blink)

**Table code:**

```
<table id="employee_grid" id="box-table-a" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="border-radius:10px; overflow: hidden">
<thead class="thead-inverse" align="center">
    <tr style="background-color:#20B2AA" style="color:red" class="border_bottom">
        <th data-column-id="id" data-order="desc" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">Sr.No.</th>
        <th data-column-id="date">Test Date</th>
        <th data-column-id="version">[![enter image description here][2]][2]Version</th>
        <th data-column-id="test_type">Test Type</th>
        <th data-column-id="tester">Tester</th>
        <th data-column-id="step1">step1</th>
        <th data-column-id="step2">step2</th>
        <th data-column-id="step3">step3</th>
        <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[image]

Comment: You're linking to the question which contains your answer...?

Comment: No, I mean where can I add this, in this case I can't see any `td` element may be due to bootgrid table.

Comment: It would depend how you load data in to your bootgrid table. Presumably that plugin has some events you can hook to

Comment: Ok. I will try to dig into it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you're trying to make blinking text or add text to your field.

Firstly I would suggest changing

```
<th> to <td>
```

since  is meant for headers,

Secondly you can add the "New" bit of text in by adding a div between your `<th><th/>` tags like this

```
<span class="newtxt" style="position:absolute;">New</span>
```

this should by default go to the top left of the cell.

Comment: Changed a bit code like this: `<td data-column-id="id" data-order="desc" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true"><span class="newtxt" style="position:absolute;">New</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;id</td>` but that is displayed in `td` which is now header, but I want to display this in latest record. I was thinking to display it by creating hidden `div` or `table` that will display `txt` near latest record, but if user sort column, it will not move text. Need to think something else.